# Returning a Mongoose Aggregate Function to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to return an aggregate function to Angular but I keep getting errors. I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong. I get an error telling me *Cannot read property 'aggregate' of undefined*.

 This is my route that the angular connects to:

```
router.get('/enrolledin', function(req, res) {
    var isEnrolled = Enrolled.findDetails(); //Enrolled.studentIsTaking(student);
       isEnrolled.then((user) => {
        res.json(user);
    })
        .catch((err) => {
        res.send("error found");
    });


});
```

Here's the *Enrolled.findDetails()*:

```
 module.exports.findDetails = function() {
    var x = db.enrolleds.aggregate(
        { $lookup: 
         {
             from:'classstores',
             localField:'classID',
             foreignField: 'classKey',
             as: 'matching'
         }
        }


    );
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (scroll to example) expects an array not an object.

Aside: I'm not sure why people love to use `then` and `catch` with mongoose. IMO it seems unnecessary and makes your code longer.

I would simply rewrite it your code like this:

```
router.get('/enrolledin', (req, res) => {
    Enrolled.findDetails((err, users) => {
        if (err)
            return res.send('error found', err);
        res.json(users);
    });
});

module.exports.findDetails = (callback) => {
    db.enrolleds.aggregate([
        { 
            $lookup: {
                from: 'classstores',
                localField: 'classID',
                foreignField: 'classKey',
                as: 'matching'
            }
        }
    ], callback);
};
```